# What is the correct http response code to send if server times out to process a request?

Tags: java, http, http-status-codes

I have a long running servlet, and I want to abort the process if timeout occurs. (Well long running servlet is another discussion).

Now when I abort the request at server, then shall I send HTTP 408 or HTTP 503 or some other appropriate status.

408 seems more like a client error and 503 more likes a overload/maintenance status. And can't find an appropriate response status.

Comment: I would say 504 fit better to your scenario https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.5 even if your server isn't actually gateway/proxy

Answer (score 14):

Since it is a server error it should start with 5XX.
According to Wikipedia, I think 504 is more appropriate for you,

> **504 Gateway Timeout**
>   The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

[1] https://www.checkupdown.com/status/E504.html

Answer (score 5):

408 means Request Timeout. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

> The server timed out waiting for the request. According to HTTP
> specifications: "The client did not produce a request within the time
> that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the
> request without modifications at any later time."

So I guess it is not appropriate for your case. Because the reason of timeout is server itself. (some long running process etc.)

503 means Service Unavailable. As you said, it is about overload/down issue and it also does not fit your case.

So you can just response with HTTP 500 as a general error response.

> 500 Internal Server Error: A generic error message, given when an
> unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is
> suitable.

Comment: I love that this is mostly a "non-answer" including what not to do. Great info.